# Use 'mv' command to move files except those in a specific directory

Tags: mac, bash

In Linux, I know the command `mv !(folder1|folder2) folder1` if I want to move all files in current folder, excepted folder1 and folder2, and move they in `folder1`. But these commend, doesn't work in mac terminal!

Where is the equivalent command in mac?

Comment: I'm assuming that your shell is bash. Turn on extended glob- `shopt -s extglob`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the version of bash on recent versions of macOS is a bit older than you'll find on some new Linux distros. I see version 3.2.57 on macOS High Sierra and Mojave and version 4.2.46 on RedHat Enterprise Linux 7.

Here's some syntax you can use to exclude the directories, as you've specified:

```
# move everything but dir1 & dir2 into dir1
mv *[^dir1dir2]* dir1
```

And, the nice thing is, the syntax above ought to work in bash on both macOS and Linux.

Comment: The Macos  bash version is the latest under GPL version 2

Comment: Is there a more simple approach to remember it?  in zsh it's also good!

Comment: Do you mean, "is there simpler syntax" or "can you explain the syntax above so that it's easy to remember"? I'm not sure which you're going for…

Comment: I meant "is there simpler syntax". The syntax under linux is more readable when used. It's `^dir1dir2` that I don't find practical.

Comment: OK, I think there are a couple immediate options. **1.** Use the `shopt -s extglob`, as recommended above by @fd0, to use your original syntax. **2.** Think of the '^' character as meaning *not*, just like the '!' character in your original syntax. With that in mind, the two flavors of syntax are fairly similar.